# What would cause the water to stop when I turn a faucet to hot?

Tags: faucet, hot-water

When I turn the faucet to hot, the water stops running. Valves have been checked and I have hot water everywhere else.

Comment: did this just all of a sudden happen or where you gradually making your shower hotter to get it to a medium temperature?

Comment: What type of faucet?

Comment: Does it first get warm/hot and then turn off?  What happens if you open the valve part-way?

Answer (score 1):

Very small pieces of debris (very frequently rust chips in homes with older galvanized pipes) can block one side or the other of the cartridge of a shower valve.

Newer valves have replaceable cartridges than can be examined and cleaned.  Just shutoff the water, open and close the valve to relieve pressure and undo the trim plate.

*Note, examples are of Delta shower valves*

The Cartridge is usually behind a finely threaded retaining nut (bonnet nut).

[image]

Sometimes the seals break and jam..  here's a Delta cartridge and seals
[image]